# MERGING data into a table that is going to have duplicate rows

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

How can I use a merge statement or any other statement to update data from one table to another when I know that there's duplicates?

> **I've been running PowerShell and sql scripts that manipulates a txt file sent from our online e-commerce software with our product catalog
> data and inserts it into a table.**

| Inventory# | WarehouseLocation | ExtraWarehouseLocation |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Item#1 | A1B1, L4T2 | D3H8, R2D2 |

There are two comma separated columns **within the text file** that hold our item locations, with the first being the main
column, **but the e-commerce software limits this main location column to 80 characters(which is an awful design by my opinion).  So we created a second column that has the max characters a field can hold.**

---

Now that we split these columns user entry errors are taking over and locations are starting to be duplicated

| Inventory# | WarehouseLocation | ExtraWarehouseLocation |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Item#1 | A1B1, L4T2, D3H8 | D3H8, R2D2 |

**The table I have combines both columns into a single column and now they have duplicates.**

| Inventory# | WarehouseLocation |
| --- | --- |
| Item#1 | A1B1, L4T2, D3H8, D3H8, R2D2 |

Within my table I had a Inventory#, WarehouseLocation, Active columns so when the daily scripts would run it would merge the new data with the old.

| LocationId | Inventory# | WarehouseLocation | Active |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Item#1 | A1B1 | 1 |
| 2 | Item#1 | L4T2 | 1 |
| 3 | Item#1 | D3H8 | 1 |
| 4 | Item#1 | D3H8 | 1 |
| 5 | Item#1 | R2D2 | 1 |
| 6 | Item#1 | Z3P4 | 0 |

So step# 1 I would set the locations active column 2 false

```
UPDATE ChannelAdvisorProductLocation 
SET Active = 0;
```

Step# 2 merge the old data but if it matched set the active column to 1, that way I could keep track of old location data that was removed from the e-commerce site but keep track of it on our end.

```
MERGE INTO ChannelAdvisorProductLocation AS T                    
USING ( 
        SELECT InventoryNumber, TRIM(split.[value]) AS loc
        FROM ChannelAdvisorProduct p
        CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(COALESCE(p.WarehouseLocation, 'NA'), ',') AS split
        GROUP BY InventoryNumber, split.[value] HAVING COUNT(*) = 1 
) 
AS S(InventoryNumber, NewLocation)
ON (T.InventoryNumber = S.InventoryNumber AND T.WarehouseLocation = S.NewLocation)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET Active = 1
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
    INSERT(InventoryNumber, WarehouseLocation)
    VALUES(S.InventoryNumber, S.NewLocation);
```

Herein lies my problem because with the duplicate locations the merge fails. To band aide the situation I've been running a delete statement instead of the UPDATE SET ACTIVE =0

```
DELETE FROM ChannelAdvisorProductLocation
```

but this is not what I'm going to want to use to track old location data.

I was hoping I could fix this with an outer join or a subquery but none of these queries find duplicates for some reason

```
DELETE child FROM ChannelAdvisorProductLocation child
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT MIN(LocationId) as RowId, InventoryNumber, WarehouseLocation 
    FROM ChannelAdvisorProductLocation parent
    GROUP BY InventoryNumber, WarehouseLocation   
) as parent 
ON parent.RowId = child.LocationId 


DELETE 
FROM ChannelAdvisorProductLocation
WHERE LocationId NOT IN
(
 SELECT MIN(LocationId) as maxId 
 FROM [ChannelAdvisorProductLocation]
 GROUP BY [InventoryNumber], [WarehouseLocation], Quantity 
)

SELECT * 
FROM ChannelAdvisorProductLocation l
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT *, 
    RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY [InventoryNumber], [WarehouseLocation]                               
    ORDER BY LocationId) rank
    FROM ChannelAdvisorProductLocation 
) p on p.LocationId = l.LocationId
WHERE rank > 1
```

ERRORS
MERGE statement fails because the target matches more than one row.

I've tried doing something with a temp table as well but feel like that's heading in the wrong direction.

**The best solution would be too use our custom column we created in the e-commerce software as the main location column** but for many reasons including ease, of use and multiple users new and old not following strict guidelines. It would just turn both columns into a complete disaster.

Tried deleting with a join statement and using a temp table, but the merge fails because there is duplicate rows.

Comment: The real problem appears to be you are storing delimited data; fixing your design should be the priority.

Comment: `There are two comma separated columns that hold our item locations` -> why? Why not store these relationally so you can have actual unique constraints?

Comment: Due to the constraints of proprietary e-commerce software to be able to store more than a single location in the location column we have to do delimited. There's no other option at this time. Unless you can convince Channel Advisor developers to properly store location data. Also storing relationally "yes" that is exactly what I'm trying to do which is the whole point to the question. Because of the bad data or duplicated locations the queries and the merge statement is not working.

Comment: Bad database design will lead to problems, such as this.

Comment: **I've been running PowerShell and sql scripts that manipulates a txt file sent from our online e-commerce software with our product catalog data and inserts it into a table.**

Comment: There is nothing that forces you to use merge, you can use update and delete as separate statements. My rule of thumb is, if you can't figure out merge (or pivot) issues, skip it and make it a normal statement

Answer (score 0):

```
MERGE INTO ChannelAdvisorProductLocation AS T                    
USING ( 
        SELECT InventoryNumber, TRIM(split.[value]) AS loc
        FROM ChannelAdvisorProduct p
        CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(COALESCE(p.WarehouseLocation, 'NA'), ',') AS split
        GROUP BY InventoryNumber, split.[value] HAVING COUNT(*) = 1 
) 
AS S(InventoryNumber, NewLocation)
ON (T.InventoryNumber = S.InventoryNumber AND T.WarehouseLocation = S.NewLocation)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET Active = 1
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
    INSERT(InventoryNumber, WarehouseLocation)
    VALUES(S.InventoryNumber, S.NewLocation);
```

From this code of yours I am assuming that **ChannelAdvisorProduct** is your new data table and **ChannelAdvisorProductLocation** is the table with old data.

So preprocess the table **ChannelAdvisorProduct** into a temp table to split the comma separated values before merging.

Also I tried to re run the scenario in [Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/9wlfWhOB) and it seems to work fine.
Please Correct me if I am getting something wrong.

Comment: Appreciate your effort, but decided @siggemannen suggestion which is also a good life decision. For the MERGE to work it requires that the source and target tables to not have any duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to close this question out with what I used to solve the problem with the suggestion of @siggemannen's comment.

3 steps I took, first create a temp table and insert the split location columns with the inventory number

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS  #TempLocationValuesTable;    

SELECT InventoryNumber, TRIM(split.[value]) AS [Location]
INTO #TempLocationValuesTable
FROM ChannelAdvisorProduct p        
CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(COALESCE(p.WarehouseLocation, 'NA'), ',') AS split
GROUP BY InventoryNumber, split.[value] 
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1;
GO
```

Then perform an insert and then an update into the target table.

```
INSERT INTO ChannelAdvisorProductLocation (InventoryNumber, WarehouseLocation, ModifiedLocation)
SELECT t.InventoryNumber, t.[Location], t.[Location] 
FROM #TempLocationValuesTable t
LEFT JOIN ChannelAdvisorProductLocation l
    ON l.InventoryNumber = t.InventoryNumber AND l.WarehouseLocation = t.[Location] 
    WHERE l.InventoryNumber IS NULL;
GO

UPDATE ChannelAdvisorProductLocation 
SET Active = 1
FROM #TempLocationValuesTable p
    JOIN ChannelAdvisorProductLocation l
    ON l.InventoryNumber = p.InventoryNumber AND l.WarehouseLocation = p.[Location];
GO
```

In conclusion, suggestions to change the database structure was and still is **IMPOSSIBLE**. The data that I receive from our online e-commerce database can either be exported in a .txt or .xls format. I can choose the columns that are included in it but that's the extent of any structure changes. I then BULK INSERT that file into a table that I base all my data transformations off of.

Finally **Yes**, the entire point of the MERGE problem was to transform bad relational database structure into a proper data structure that we can consume locally/internally.

One final point before closing. @siggemannen's comment is really what should have been my first course of action. But I tend to slip into the mindset of when looking for a solution to a problem is to use the most popular method, the newest, the easiest or in this case the the method that was working. "Most" problems do not have one solution.